# Loading JRuby script from the Java classpath

Tags: maven, jruby

I have a simple maven project that looks like this:

- $PROJ/src/main/java/path-to-classes/InstallerLoader.java
- $PROJ/src/main/resources/installer.rb

This is what InstallerLoader.java looks like:

```
package com.mycompany;

import org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer;
import org.jruby.embed.PathType;

public class InstallerLoader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Running..");
        ScriptingContainer container = new ScriptingContainer();
        container.runScriptlet(PathType.CLASSPATH, "/installer.rb");
    }
}
```

And this is what installer.rb looks like:

```
require 'optparse'

options = { :verbose => false}
optparse = OptionParser.new do |opts|
    opts.on('-v', '--verbose', 'Verbose output') do
        options[:verbose] = true
    end
end

optparse.parse!

puts options[:verbose]
```

When I try to run this, it doesn't seem to load installer.rb. There is no stack trace or anything else that would indicate that the installer.rb was not loaded. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that finally got it to work:

```
container.setArgv(args);
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/installer.rb");
container.runScriptlet(is, "installer.rb");
```

Answer (score 2):

The classpath filename shouldn't start with a `/`.  It should just be:

```
container.runScriptlet(PathType.CLASSPATH, "installer.rb");
```

This is a [quirky undocumented aspect](http://weaklyreachable.blogspot.com/2010/06/leading-slash-vs-classloadergetresource.html) of Java's ClassLoader API (which is of course being used under the covers by the ScriptingContainer to load files from the classpath).